# front (Dashboard) and back (Central Service REST Server) end are not communicating

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, server, ocpp

I followed a GitHub project to create an ev-server with dashboard. Everything seems to be working fine but the dashboard does not seems to be able to connect to the back end server (e.g. unable to register account and login on the dashboard webpage). According to the GitHub page, a Google reCaptCha key is needed to allow communication between the 2 end and so I did but it didn't go as planned.

link to the project: https://github.com/sap-labs-france/ev-server

partial config file for back end server:

```
  "CentralSystems": [
    {
      "type": "ocpp",
      "implementation": "soap",
      "protocol": "https",
      "host": "localhost",
      "port": 8000,
      "debug": false
    },
    {
      "type": "ocpp",
      "implementation": "json",
      "protocol": "wss",
      "host": "localhost",
      "port": 8010,
      "keepaliveinterval": 30,
      "debug": false
    }
  ],
  "CentralSystemRestService": {
    "protocol": "https",
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 8020,
    "sslKey": "",
    "sslCert": "",
    "sslCa": [],
    "userTokenKey": "YourSecretKey",
    "userTokenLifetimeHours": 12,
    "userDemoTokenLifetimeDays": 365,
    "userTechnicalTokenLifetimeDays": 365,
    "passwordWrongNumberOfTrial": 3,
    "passwordBlockedWaitTimeMin": 5,
    "captchaSecretKey": "secret_key",
    "captchaScore": 0.25,
    "debug": false
  },
  "CentralSystemFrontEnd": {
    "protocol": "https",
    "host": "localhost",
    "port": 8020
  },
```

config file for dashboard:
`  GNU nano 6.2                               ev-dashboard/src/assets/config.json                                        {
"CentralSystemServer": {
"protocol": "https",
"host": "localhost",
"port": 8020,
"pollIntervalSecs": 10
},
"Authorization": {
"debug": false
},
"Asset": {
"maxImageKb": 800
},
"User": {
"maxPictureKb": 150,
"captchaSiteKey": "secret_key"
},
"Tenant": {
"maxLogoKb": 150
},
"Company": {
"maxPictureKb": 150
},
"Site": {
"maxPictureKb": 800
},
"SiteArea": {
"maxPictureKb": 800
},
"Car": {
"url": ""
},

"Advanced": {
"debounceTimeNotifMillis": 50,
"debounceTimeSearchMillis": 500
},
"Debug": {
"enabled": true
}
}
`

I know nothing regarding this field and what I did was just purely following the guide. I did some research but I am still not that familiar with how this whole thing work. Therefore if you can explain it in a rather simple way, I would really appreciate it! Thanks!